# React-Admin "Get List" DataProvider

Tags: reactjs, react-admin

I'm starting to use the `react-admin` package.
 I am blocked in my development because I would like to make a `Select` with the data of another `Resource`. And that's why I use `ReferenceField` but I don't know why I get this error when I use this element.

```js
Error: The response to 'GET_LIST' must be like { data : [{ id: 123, ...}, ...] }, but at least one received data item do not have an 'id' key. The dataProvider is probably wrong for 'GET_LIST
```

Here is the data that I receive from my API:

```js
[{"_id":"5e3ec3baa6480d002b24ea90","name_promo":"test","years":"2019-01-01T00:00:00.000Z","__v":0}]
```

For information, I use the Provider `ra-data-json-server`

Here is my code:

```js
import React from 'react';
import {
    Create,
    SimpleForm,
    TextInput,
    ReferenceInput,
    SelectInput,
} from 'react-admin';

const CreateUser = (props) => (
    <Create {...props}>
        <SimpleForm>
            <TextInput source="lastName" label="Prénom" />
            <TextInput source="firstName" label="Nom" />
            <TextInput source="email" label="Email" />
            <TextInput source="role" label="Role" />
            <ReferenceInput  label="Session" source="id" reference="sessions"  >
                <SelectInput optionText="name_promo"/>
            </ReferenceInput >
        </SimpleForm>
    </Create>
);

export default CreateUser;
```

Comment: Can you show us what your DataProvider looks like?

Answer (score 0):

Your data is being returned from the API with its id field named `"_id"` instead of the required `"id"`.

We solved this problem by adding the following to our (python) API.

```
myData = mongo.get(...)
for x in myData:
    x['id'] = x['_id']  // Now each record has both '_id' and 'id'
return {'data': myData}, HTTPStatus.CREATED
```

Answer (score 0):

ra-admin by default use the keys **id** and **name**, if your API call is not returning that firm you must declare it as a prop on the component

```html
<ReferenceInput label="Session" source="id" reference="sessions" >
  <SelectInput optionText="name_promo" optionValue="_id" />
</ReferenceInput>
```